# People blocked from asking questions should be blocked from posting discussions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, collectives, discussions-space

People are abusing public discussions to ask for help. Not only they are abusing the site and evading restrictions, they are also wasting time of people in collectives. They post non-discussion topics which often should be questions. These "discussion topics" are plagued by the same quality issues that their questions on main had, for which they received the automatic ban. The system should not allow them to evade restrictions by posting their questions as discussions.

Comment: I am only sorry that I cannot upvote this at least a hundred times.

Comment: Feature request: get rid of discussions (until properly fixed). By properly fixed, I mean red flag automations, syncing with question bans, moderator tooling, rate limiting, and an API (for bots). Did I miss anything (probably yes)?

Comment: @Fastnlight: Applying the *'very low quality'* filter (used to move questions into some of the review queues) to discussion posts, perhaps?.

Comment: @PeterMortensen that would imply adding review queues for discussions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This change has been made. Users banned from asking questions will not be able to create new posts in Discussions.