# If we don't have any programming collectives other than R and PHP, what's the point of them and why keep them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, collectives

I've just noticed that R and PHP are the *only* programming languages with their own Collective. A lot of the "discussions" in the PHP Collective are more fitted to be questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77811015/does-it-make-sense-to-throw-an-exception-in-a-try-block-in-php) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77140039/how-do-i-run-php-in-verbose-mode)). If you are thinking that it would be a good place to hold discussions, why don't we have a Collective for other programming languages except for R and PHP—we could do JavaScript, Python, HTML, CSS, Node.js; the list goes on and on! So why do we have this oddball?

Comment: To be fair, discussions are going site-wide in a test starting.... next month, so some time between 3 hours from now and a month from now?

Comment: Instead of creating more collectives, just get rid of them. IMO, PHP is entirely deprecated, so I don't see the point of it having a collective, and why of all languages, PHP was selected, but either way, there are so many programming languages that making a collective for each of them would probably not be the best idea.

Comment: "we don't have any programming collectives other than PHP"? I guess [R Language](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language) is taking the L then?

Comment: @Laurel R is just one letter, PHP is 3 so it's more of a language. err, well, 2, with one repeating, but, still more!

Comment: @Laurel I have added the R language to my post.

Comment: but otherwise, Yes, of course, the solution to collectives being too exclusive is to remove them, not expand them! i 100% agree with that idea, despite my summary making a sarcastic remark about that being an absurd idea. Until they have features that are better walled off in a collective than open site-wide, they don't have a reason to exist. I don't yet know how articles could exist outside of collectives, but surely being locked to only allowing collectives to spawn them is a poor solution. Discussions will probably work no better or worse without the collective.

Comment: @Fastnlight: Re *"PHP is entirely deprecated"*: It may not be favoured by the cool kids, but it is not deprecated.

Comment: I deprecate PHP every day, sometimes twice a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primarily because Collectives is really still mostly an experiment. It was meant to be a sub community area with a few extra features to help facilitate that community feeling like a sub community and not just another way to filter content. If it is to continue existing, I'd expect it to continue gaining new languages/technical areas over the next few years.

Discussions is an experiment to test a new content type and was limited to collectives so that it can exist in a smaller area and not impact the site as a whole. Discussions is [expanding to all tags in February](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427864/discussions-update-expansion-to-all-tags-in-february) to test whether or not it will see wider usage/engagement when not contained within a collective.

Comment: *chuckles* and I love how the post has 51 downvotes

Comment: I think discussions could be useful.. just.. i think the creation of new discussions needs to be far more controlled than just a link sitting in the side bar. A more chat-like realtime interface would also likely make it better

Comment: In a sense... my idea of a better implementation for discussions would be an improved chat with language-tag rooms that could, on demand, spawn discussions as needed that were just mini chatrooms that were advertised to the host chatroom, similar to how stars currently. wait... i just described what chat currently is.

Comment: I still like the idea of collectives as a honeypot for low-quality posts and spam that doesn't belong on the main site.